# How to convert linear equation to slope-intercept form?

Tags: equation-solving

Is there a general way (that can be applied to other linear equations too) to convert linear equation to slope-intercept form?

For example, I have linear equation:

$ 6x+3y=5 $

I want a method that convert such equation to:

$ y=-2x+\frac{5}{3} $

**Question:** Is there a general method to do that with Wolfram Mathematica?

---

I tried this:

```
Solve[6 x + 3 y == 5, y]
```

But it gave me this output:

$ \left\{\left\{y\to \frac{1}{3} (5-6 x)\right\}\right\} $

Comment: Solve[ 6 x + 3 y == 5, y] // Expand

Comment: @irchans Thank you.

Comment: @Nasser I think we should keep your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

```
convert[eq_, x_, y_] := Module[{slope, intercept, sol},
  sol = y /. First@Solve[eq, y];
  slope = Coefficient[sol, x];
  intercept = Simplify[sol - (slope*x)];
  {slope, intercept}
  ]
```

Call it as

```
ClearAll[y,x];
eq = 6 x + 3 y == 5;
{slope, intercept} = convert[eq, x, y]
```

$ \left\{-2,\frac{5}{3}\right\} $

```
myEquation = y == slope*x + intercept
```

$ y=\frac{5}{3}-2 x $

Comment: Thank you for answer. After running `ClearAll[y, x] l
eq = 6 x + 3 y == 5;
{slope, intercept} = convert[eq, x, y]` I am also getting second output `l Null`. Is that second output something useful or I should ignore it?

Comment: You can easily copy Mathematica output in Latex by: Select the part of the output that you want to copy as latex, after right click on it, after click on "Copy as" and after click on "Latex". You can paste content inside `$  $` (be sure that space is left on each side between pasted content and `$`s) and you can put all this in post which will be automatically rendered as Latex

Comment: @vasili111 sorry, the extra 'l' was a cut/paste thing. I meant ";". corrected.